# Blazor InputSelect - How do I set the text color of an element after being selected?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have an InputSelect-Element. The text color of each element varies.

This a little code example.

```
<InputSelect id="id" class="form-select" @bind-Value=@SelectedItem>
    @for (var item = 0; item < 5; item++)
    {
        if (item > 1)
        {
            <option style="color:red" value="@item">@item</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option value="@item">@item</option>
        }
    }
</InputSelect>
```

Dropdown looks like this:

[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqc95.jpg)

After choice:

[Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM9YL.jpg)

Why does the color of the choosen element is black again? Is there a workaround to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with Radzen:

```
<RadzenDropDown id="id" Data=@entries class="form-select" Placeholder="Auswählen" @bind-Value=@SelectedItem>
<Template>
    <span style="color:@TextColor(@context)">@context</span>
</Template>
```

Answer (score -1):

Now you are changing the color only for the dropdown menu, but you don't have style for InputSelect.

Try to add to your InputSelect this:

```
style="color:@TextColor(model.yourModel);"
```

and in your code behind this:

```
private void TextColor(string text) {
    if (Convert.ToInt32(text) > 1)
    {
        return "#ff0000";  // red
    }
    else
    {
        return "#ffffff";  // black
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Same behaviour.